# Web Service Authorization Authentication

Tags: web-services, iis, authentication, authorization, asmx

I have a problem for a few months now...

I have a web service and a client using the web service.

When i try to add the web service to the client(with "Add Web Reference.."), i search for web services on the local machine and finds it. but when i click it in order to add it to the project i get a prompt dialog asking me for username and password.

I recall times when i didn't have this dialog and I'm not sure why this happens now...

the Web.config file of the web service contains `<authentication mode="Windows" />`

Few details:

- I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Standard.
- the programs are written in C#.
- I'm using IIS 5.1 and the web service configured only with "Integrated Windows Authentication" checked.

in my windows XP I'm using (in order to login) a user name and password.

No matter what i do to add the web Service to the client i can't add it. it fails.

Comment: Have you upgraded to vs2008 recently?

Comment: Check to see if your web project (client) is running on vs2008's built-in web server...  under Project -> Properties -> Web section.

Comment: i tried to changed it to use Local IIS, but still the same. when i try to connect to the web service i get the same dialog. and when i cancel it i get "You are not authorized to view this page 
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied."

Comment: Can you check those same settings on the web service project and try connecting with both options?

Comment: You solved it! thanks!!!!!!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your web project (client) is running on vs2008's built-in web server... under Project -> Properties -> Web section.

If not, can you check those same settings on the web service project and try connecting with both options?

That should do it.

**from comments above

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you check and see if you have the option NTLM Authentication checked under Project Properties -> Web. If you uncheck this option you should be able to add the Web Service without having to authenticate.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378749.aspx